# 【Flink 1.3】Class not found: org.apache.kafka.common.ByteArrayDeserializer

Tags: apache-flink

I am using Flink 1.3 and flink-connector-kafka-0.10_2.11 to work with Kafka with following simple code(at the end)

I create a fat jar and package the `kafka-client` module(https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/0.10.1.1) in this  fat jar and don't package flink related module in my fat jar, and submit the application using

```
flink run -m  yarn-cluster -c com.my.FlinkKafkaTest  -yn 2 -ys 1 /tmp/learing.flink.1.3.0-0.1.jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

But when the application starts to run, it complains that org.apache.kafka.common.ByteArrayDeserializer is not found, but I have packaged the kafka-client module in my fat jar. I would ask where the problem is,and why ByteArrayDeserializer is not found

Thanks!

```
import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.{CheckpointingMode, TimeCharacteristic}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer010
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._

object FlinkKafkaTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime)
    env.enableCheckpointing(1000)
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setCheckpointingMode(CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    val props = createConsumerProperties()
    val topic = "flink_topic"
    val ds = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010[String](topic, new SimpleStringSchema(), props))
    ds.print()
    env.execute()
  }

  def createConsumerProperties():Properties = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "a:2181,b:2181,c:2181/kafka")
    props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "d:9001,e:9001,f:9001")
    props.setProperty("group.id", "FlinkKafkaTest")
    props.setProperty("security.protocol", "PLAINTEXT")
    props.put("kerberos.domain.name", "hadoop.com")
    props
  }
```

}

Comment: Are you sure you've put kafka-client in your fat jar? You can check doing `jar tf /tmp/learing.flink.1.3.0-0.1.jar-with-dependencies.jar | grep ByteArrayDeserializer`

Comment: Yes，I do. But, when I put the kafka client jar into flink/lib, and remove the kafka client jar from the fat jar, it works. I don' t know why.

Comment: I think that's how it is supposed to be. The flink framework does the plumbing, while your custom code does the business logic. So the kafka part being plumbing, it should be available in flink/lib. It is explained here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/debugging_classloading.html